# Difference between the wave forms in the water and in the Young double slit experiment

Tags: optics, waves, water, interference, double-slit-experiment

We can observe when we cause a slight disturbance at two points on the water surface which is intially totally undisturbed , it will form water waves which would look like as shown in below image:

[image]

we can observe that there are constructive and destructive interferences at some places and also which lies in between these type of interferences (that is between fully destructive and fully constructive) . We notice that it doesnt need screen to show the interference effects at all , so why in YDSE we need screen to show the interference patterns, is it because we cant be able to observe the interference being happen in air or any other medium from our naked eyes?

Comment: Have you looked at the dimensions of diffraction of light? Water is in centimeters. This may help ,  http://www.studyphysics.ca/newnotes/20/unit04_light/chp1719_light/lesson58.htm . In example  1 distance between slits is  0.096cm . particularly the very last paragraph is of interest.

Comment: I don't really have an answer for you, but what makes you think that we wouldn't observe the same thing if we had a reliable way to trace a path of electrons after the slits? The screen was a necessity when it came to firing one electron at a time. Try doing the same with one water molecule at a time and tell me what you see.

Comment: @bleuofblue I think the question is about light, the classical double slit experiment

Comment: I ask the same thing though, if we had a way to trace the path of photons after the slits, would we not notice the same pattern of interference as the water? What happens when the region after the slits contains a medium like smoke which could highlight a laser path? The screen to me is just a tool to measure whats happening at any set distance from the source. Plop a detecting screen into that water, and we would have interference no matter what distance from the slits

Comment: read the last paragraph in the link I give, you can see single slit interference using your fingers

Comment: I read that @annav thanks , but then whats the use of screen in YDSE ?

Comment: If we are able to see with our eyes itself the diffraction/interference

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer to have a permanent record. In exmple 1 the distance of the screen is 13 meters, in order to be able to separate the fringes

Comment: I see thanks you may put that as answer i will accept it @annav

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer  Thanks, but it is a sketchy answer, and I do not feel up to editing more details.

Comment: I see okay Mam/Sir as you say

Answer (score 1):

The screen is used simply because it makes the interference effect easier to see and to record and analyse. As is the case with the picture of the interference of water waves which you included in your question, the light interferes with itself everywhere. The use of a screen allows you to see the interference along a straight line, measure the fringes at a fixed distance from the slits, photograph them, and so on.

Comment: Can you give a explanation how the screen shows the pattern , i mean i know that screen will be having interference but i mean to say how the waves which are getting transferred there are making the **colours in the screen** ? Although i understannd your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need the screen because you do not want to stare in the sun with your eyes even if you were doing it through a peep-hole. Imagine adjusting the size of the diaphragm (of the slits) to see if there is already enough light has already fallen on your retina.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that a water wave in a single slit will NOT make an interference pattern ... but light will!  Water and light are similar but also very different. In the DSE there is NO light in the dark areas .... photons will travel to areas that are more "resonant" (path length is a multiple of wavelength), this is quantum mechanics/optics.

Comment: What makes you say this? If the slit has the right size compared with the wavelength it will produce a diffraction/interference pattern. You can see this in simulations and videos of ripple tank waves.

Comment: @nasu you will see in many wave tanks that there are reflections off the edges which cause additional waves.  It is a common misconception as the Huygens principle (which is best for matter waves) is incorrectly applied to light especially in high school.  Huygens for light requires the source to be broken into many sources.  In sound waves sources there are many reflections off edges as well .... but interferences in sound are also caused by walls etc.  There is no interference for sound from a single slit if we are in open space.

Comment: Also note that diffraction and interference are 2 separate concepts .... but they commonly are used to refer to both.

Comment: @PhysicsDave This is correct but it's very hard to convince anyone. I have tried to find real images or videos that prove interference patterns form when water waves go through a single slit but there are none.

Comment: @BillAlsept yes it's impossible .... the historical textbooks shy away from the concept .... briefly mentioning single slit diffraction and quickly jumping to 2 slits ... where the math can easily start.